# CSS selector. Select one of two classes with the similar name

Tags: c#, css, anglesharp

I try to parse web-site using AngleSharpe and I have the following case:

```
<div class="list another">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>

...

<div class="list">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

I need to get class "list", but I'm getting the first "list another" by order.

```
var selector = @"div[class$='list']";
var cell = document.QuerySelectorAll(selector);
```

I tried to use the following various:

```
"div[class$=list]"
"div.list"
```

When I'm using selector with parent class of "list", which differ from parent class of "list another" like "parent class > list", I don't get nothing.

Please give me advice how will be right or where necessary see to solve this issue

Comment: Is your requirement - you want to select the 2nd appearing .list from the dom ?

Comment: Yes, it's my requirement

Comment: give the parent class as list-another. Here both the divs are having the same class name - list . The first one is having list and another as class. Both are seperate classes

Answer (score 1):

Try this, selects all dom elements with class .list, but not with class .another. So you will be able to select the second div exclusively

```
     document.querySelectorAll(".list:not(.another)");
```

Comment: It returns 0 elements. It's very strange. Perhaps this is a feature of the AngleSharp

Comment: console.log the output

Comment: After query variable doesn't contain elements. Need additional debugging

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others you can do that fully using CSS Selectors:

```cs
var config = Configuration.Default;
// note: ideally load your document from a URL directly if applicable
var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config)
    .OpenAsync(res => res.Content(@"<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Test Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class=""list another""></div>
<div class= ""list""></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>"));
document.QuerySelector(".list:not(.another)").ClassList.Dump();
```

The code above uses LINQPad (see `Dump()`), with AngleSharp 0.14.

[image: LINQPad Output]

Note that this is different from just using `.list`:

[image: LINQPad with the previous query]

Finally, you can take advantage of `QuerySelectorAll` and just put LINQ afterwards.

To confirm, going over all elements having the `list` class is like:

```cs
document.QuerySelectorAll(".list").Select(m => m.ClassList).Dump();
```

where we get

[image: Iterating over the results]

For instance, the following works:

```cs
document
  .QuerySelectorAll(".list")
  .Where(m => m.ClassList.Count() == 1)
  .Select(m => m.ClassList)
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .Dump()
```

This gives us exactly the same as the selector above `.list:not(.another)` even though it is much more constraint (instead of knowing which other classes *should not* appear, it just makes sure that *only* the desired one has been placed).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone! It didn't work because I didn't notice that this class is changing by script in browser. And because of this class unavailable in AngleSharp. I found "nonscript" section.